# Proxy server to fetch Ads response from IMA

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ad-manager, vast, google-ima, imasdk

I have a use case to measure if IMA sdk is making calls to its VAST ad server or not. For that I am planning to setup and intermediate server and provide ads response via this server. Is this possible with IMA? Will this have any impact on ads fill rate etc.